# Updating cover picture of my facebook page using graph API is not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I tried to change my facbook page cover picture using graph API. Unfortunately it is  showing an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

I am the admin of my page. Graph api call is given below.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{Page id}?cover={Image id}&method=POST&access_token={Access token}
```

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/#publishing you can only update the `cover` photo if you use a Page Access Token with the appropriate permissions.

Using

```
POST /{page-id}
```

with the POST body

```
cover={Image id}
```

should work. Your Graph API call from above seems to be a GET request in contrary. Note that the image must already be uplaoded to Facebook. You need to pass a valid `object_id` as `{Image id}`.